# c9.io mongodb connection url example

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cloud9-ide

Can anyone give me an example of a mongodb connection URL in c9.io? I'm wanting to connect to their local instance of mongodb and I have mongod running in the background.

Here is what I'm trying to use:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
function ConnectToDB(mongoUrl){
    var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
    //var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/my_database_name';
    var url = mongoUrl || 'mongodb://' + process.env.IP + ":27017/test";
    // Use connect method to connect to the Server
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if(err){
           console.log(err); 
        }
      console.log("Connected correctly to server");
      return db;
    });
}
```

It doesn't even log, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try without the `:27017` port in the URL

Comment: var url = mongoUrl || ('mongodb://' + process.env.IP + '/test'); Didnt work either :/

Comment: did you even call the function `ConnectToDB()` ?

Comment: I'm using this as the caller and I'm calling it via a test

Comment: var SaveData = function(tableName, newModel, schemaFile){
        var db = ConnectToDB();
        console.log(db);
        var doc = db.collection(tableName).find({ _id: newModel._id });
        if(SchemaMatch(newModel, schemaFile)){
            doc.save(newModel);
        } else {
            console.log(" SaveData |  newModel != schema ".bgRed.white + schemaFile.bgRed.green);
        }
        
        db.close();
    };

Comment: And if I put a consolelog after the var url it will log it, its just the second it hits the MongoClient.connect it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work my logic was off a bit :p

```
function OpenDB(mongoUrl, callBack){
    var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
    //var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/my_database_name';
    var url = mongoUrl || "mongodb://" + process.env.IP + "/test";
    console.log(url.bgWhite.blue);
    // Use connect method to connect to the Server
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if(err){
           console.log(err);
        }
      console.log("Connected correctly to server");
      callBack(db);
      db.close();
    });
}
```